# What happens if you do not pay your bills?

Tags: jagged-alliance-2

I'm playing on the jagged alliance 2 [1.13 fanpatch/mod](http://ja2v113.pbworks.com/w/page/4218339/FrontPage). And while you pay the AIM mercs up front, you get an invoice for the MERC mercs. Is there any consequence for not paying your bills? (And is there a difference between vanilla, and the fanpatch?